# How TFS 2015 agent assign coverage results to SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild?

Tags: sonarqube, tfsbuild, sonar-runner

Trying to reproduce the steps that a TFS agent perform with the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild. 
I am not able to locate where the Agent injects the name of the coverage results file. The documentation [states](http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770) that a coverage file should be parsed to an xml file, but digging into the powershell at the SonarQubePostTest task there is no call to codecoverage.exe, neither a setting to the `sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths` variable.

How TFS 2015 agent assign coverage results to SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild in order to manually reproduce the call of the agent?

**P.S.**
I am using vNext build definition, it is the compilation of some c# dll projects, after the build, then a set of test run using VS test.

Comment: Which one are you using XAML build or Vnext build? Could you share your related  build definition settings ? Are you using publish test results task?

Answer (score -1):

There should be a SonarQube begin analysis task before msbuild and a SonarQube end analysis task after msbuild.

The completed Begin Analysis definition. This just some configuration to connect to sonarqube server

[image]

The completed Begin Analysis definition
[image]

> The End Analysis task should be used to create a step that is executed
>   after the “Visual Studio Test” task step if you want SonarQube to show
>   code coverage data. In any case, it should be run after the “Visual
>   Studio Build” step. The End Analysis task finalizes the analysis
>   (computation of the clones, metrics, and analysis for languages other
>   than .Net), and sends the analysis results to the SonarQube server.

More details please see this MSDN blog: [Build Tasks for SonarQube Analysis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/24/build-tasks-for-sonarqube-analysis/)

Comment: thank you for trying to answer my question, but your comment as well as your images did not solve the question,  neither your link to the documentation. **I am not asking how to setup the SonarQube analysis task**